# Help with nabla operator

Tags: calculus, matrices, vectors

I am getting confused by two statements, namely $a\nabla$ and $\nabla\cdot c$ where

$$a = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\ A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33}\end{array}\right]$$

$$c=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} \\
A_{21} \\
A_{31}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is it
$$
 a\nabla= \left[\begin{array}{ccc}A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\ A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33}\end{array}\right]\begin{bmatrix}\partial_x \\
\partial_y \\
\partial_z
\end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix}A_{11}\partial_x + A_{12}\partial_y + A_{13}\partial_z \\
A_{21}\partial_x + A_{22}\partial_y + A_{23}\partial_z \\
A_{13}\partial_x + A_{23}\partial_y + A_{33}\partial_z
\end{bmatrix}
$$
?

And if I have

$$\nabla\cdot c =\begin{bmatrix}\partial_x \\
\partial_y \\
\partial_z
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} \\
A_{21} \\
A_{31}
\end{bmatrix} = \partial_xA_{11} + \partial_y A_{21} + \partial_z A_{31} $$

Thanks in advance

Comment: You got both right. What is the confusion?

Comment: I thought I may have misunderstood the definition. So thank you for alleviating my anxiety! +1